# Efficient NoSQL data model for large collections

Tags: angular, database, firebase, nosql, data-modeling

**Scenario:**

There are 1,000,000 coordinates (pixels) in an element.

A coordinate consists of `x: number, y: number`

Users select a single coordinate to 'activate'

**Objective to User:**

Show a count of unique coordinates activated.

i.e. 247,456 out of 1,000,000 coordinates have been activated

**DB Objectives:**

How should such a large data set be modeled in NoSQL?

**Approach #1**
Pre-populate a collection with the possible coordinates and remove them / increment a counter as the coordinates are activated

Searching through the list would be expensive, but only improve as more coordinates are activated.

**Approach #2**
Have a growing collection of documents as the coordinates are activated and increment.

Reading/writing would become increasingly expensive without an efficient architecture.

Comment: If I understand the question, you are actually asking *how to count the number of activated child nodes with a node*. If that's correct, a simple counter will do it; when a node is activated, increment the counter. When deactivated, decrement the counter. There's no way we can suggest a model without knowing what kind of queries will be run or what's going to be done with the data. The structure suggested in your question may work, or may not. Is this multi-user? When will reads and writes be done? By how many users? How often? Can you use transactions? See? Too many variables as is.

Comment: I won't need to recount the nodes that are activated. Anyone can come and activate the node and once activated I want to increment a counter to keep track of total activated nodes. No transaction is needed, think of it as a pixel that gets clicked once and if that node was not already activated then activate and increment the counter

Comment: Well then, I think you have your solution! +1 for the counter! (lol)

Answer (score 0):

Use the second approach, Just give time to build a good architecture around it because that would a lot useful and further reduce the read cost of a document to delete the coordinates which is in the first approach

Comment: Can you give some insight into what a good architecture would be? For example, would it be best to create sub collections of batches of coordinates. I.e. store coordinates with x < 99 in one collection. Is there a better way to group them together?

Comment: @Flignats No. Do not go with option 2... or 1. If there is a possibility there will be 1,000,000 child nodes, neither is a good solution as to get the count you would either need to iterate over all child nodes which will take a lot of time, or load them all in and count them (iin an array for example) but that would overload the memory of the device.

Comment: True, but I only placed approach #2 to get the conversation going. What would be an efficient way to keep track of 1,000,000 activated coordinates? A hybrid of approach #1?

Comment: @Flignats I think you provided your own answer as outlined in the comment to your question. Keep a counter in a node and increment it when a coordinate node is activated and decrement when a coordinate node is deactivated - it's a simple, low bandwidth solution and won't require any kind of counting or recounting.

Comment: The solution still doesn't outline an approach for knowing how those nodes have been activated. I.e. I would have to search a list of nodes with an activation boolean to know its status to know to increment the counter. If a user selects node 105, 450 - I would need to know if it is previously activated or not in order to increment the counter

Comment: @Flignats I think you're missing one of the fundamental concepts with Firebase - it's a live, event-driven product. When a node is activated your app will be notified of that event and can update the counter accordingly - no polling or querying is needed. You would also know when a coordinate is deactivated and if the use case needs it, if one was added or removed.